# How to 'remember' user when you send them to a new HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, change-password

We have a web-application in which all new users get a standard password. They are redirected to a 'change Password' page when they log in with the standard password. We want to update the password there.

The problem is, when the user is send to the 'change Password' HTML page (from the login HTML), it is not known anymore who the user is. How can we modify our application (controller/ service (functions 'login'and 'changePassword' are in a service) / api) so we know who the user is when we redirect to the 'changePassword' HTML?
We are working with Angular JS.

Or what function we can add so we can request the current user from the backend?

Comment: Google "session cookie".

Comment: Or you can use localStorage or sessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the user object, you could save the user ID in the root scope, so that you can access it elsewhere.

Use a `$rootScope` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope